# How to use useState with object with interface in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
export interface IManuscript {
    heading: IManuscriptHeading;
    abstract: IShortSection;
    sections: ISection;
}

interface IManuscriptHeading {
    title: string;
    authors: Array<IAuthors>;
}

interface IAuthors {
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    url: string;
}

interface IShortSection {
    title: string;
    description: Array<string>;
}

interface ISection {
    introduction: {
        title: string;
        description: Array<string>;
    };
    hypothesis_development: IHypothesis;
    method: ISectionProps;
    results: ISectionProps;
    study_limitations: ISectionProps;
    conclusions: ISectionProps;
}

interface IHypothesis {
    short_title: string;
    title: string;
    figures: IFigure
    description: Array<string>;
}

interface IFigure {
    name: string;
    title: string;
    legend: string;
}

interface ISectionProps {
    title: string;
    description: Array<ISubsection>;
}

interface ISubsection {
    title: string;
    figures: Array<IFigure>
    tables: { title: string; data: []}
    description: Array<string>;
}
```

And I want to use it in the component. So, I wrote the following line:

```
const [manuscript, setManuscript] = useState<IManuscript>({})
```

But I get the error `Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IManuscript`. So, I modified this line as the following by adding `Partial`

```
const [manuscript, setManuscript] = useState<Partial<IManuscript>>({});
```

But now, I get the error `manuscript.heading` is possible undefined` in the following line:

```
<SectionHeader title={manuscript.heading.title} />
```

So, I made the properties optional.

```
<SectionHeader title={manuscript?.heading?.title} />
```

But, I get `Expression expected` error in another part even though I added `?` in the properties:

```
{Object.keys(manuscript?.sections?).map((key: any, index: number) => (
    <div>
    </div>
 ))}
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you should be using `Manuscript | undefined` as your type instead.

Comment: @vr., Thanks for reminding that. I forgot to include that I had also tried that. The error I get is `Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IManuscript'`. I added it in the `useState<IManuscript | undefined>({})`. Is this correct?

Comment: Remove the initial value of `{}`. Then check if `manuscript` is undefined before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Different solution to comment possibly, don't know if you need to specify undefined

```
   const [manuscript, setManuscript] = useState<IManuscript>();
      let title: string;
      if (manuscript) {
        //Do manauscript stuff here.
        title = manuscript?.heading.title;
      }
```